# Accessing inbuilt objects in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

How can we access Standard Objects say Account and Contact in salesforce through Apex?
That is , be it inserting of rows of retrivel from them in Objects

Comment: can anyone share an example making use of Account Standard Controller

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard.  You can start with something like this:

```
List<Account> accts;
Accts = [SELECT name, id, createddate FROM Account where createddate =LAST_90_DAYS];
```

That gets you a list of all accounts that meet the condition.  When you do a query like this, you'll almost always follow that up with a for loop to get at the objects returned.  That might look like this:

```
String name;
for (Account a : Accts) {
    name = a.Name;
}
```

You can also put the query (the text between the square brackets) in place of "Accts" in the "for" line.  My personal preference is to explicitly declare the list variable.  I find this clearer.  Others may prefer the more concise notation.

Keep in mind that you'll only be able to access fields that are listed in your query.

You can see more on SOQL and loops [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm)